# Enter names, display them as a list and print only the names that start with letter A from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def make_list(number):
    names=[]
    for item in range (number):
        names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter."))
    print(names)
    
number=int(input("How many names need to be entered?"))
names=make_list(number)
for i in names:
    if names[i]=="A":
        print("Name", i, "Starts with A")
```

Getting an error: Nonetype object not iterable.Any help please?

Comment: Your function `make_list` doesn't return anything, so `names` has nothing and you can't iterate on nothing. I guess you meant to `return names` at the end of `make_list`

Answer (score 1):

1. Your method doesn't return the list, so default is `None` you need to give it back from it

   ```
   def make_list(number):
       names = []
       for item in range(number):
           names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter."))
       return names
   ```
2. When you iterate over a list, the element is an item of the list, not an indice

   ```
   for name in names:
       # name is a value, a string
   ```
3. Use `str.startswith`

   ```
   if name.startswith("A")
   ```

---

```
names = make_list(number)
for name in names:
    if name.startswith("A"):
        print("Name", name, "Starts with A")
```

Answer (score 0):

You just doesn't return anything from `make_list` function and `names` variable in global scope is empty. Add `return` statement like

```
def make_list(number):
    names=[]
    for item in range (number):
        names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter."))
    print(names)
    return names
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers have mentioned, you were missing a return for `make_list`. Here is another solution. You needed to iterate through `names` and check if the first character of name, `name[0]`, is equal to A.

```
def make_list(number):
    names=[]
    for item in range (number):
        names.append(input("Enter your name with a capital letter."))
    return names
    
number=int(input("How many names need to be entered?"))
names=make_list(number)
for name in names:
    if name[0]=="A":
        print("Name", name, "Starts with A")
```